# Assertions.assertThrows returns void while it must return Throwable | JUnit 5

Tags: java, assert, junit5, assertion, throwable

I am using `JUnit 5` library and I try to use assertThrows and get the exception thrown in order to get the message of the exception. I have such piece of code:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
//import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

public class Tests {
    private static void execute() throws Exception {
        ArrayList<String> filter = ListString.filter(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3")), "4");
    }

    @Test
    public void listStringTest() {
        // This part doesn't work 
        Throwable throwable = Assertions.assertThrows(Exception.class, Tests::execute);
        assertEquals("Exception texnt", throwable.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I get the following message:

[image]

But the [documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html) says that assert throws returns `T extends Throwable`, not `void`:

[image]

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Either the documentation is wrong, or more likely you're not using the version you're thinking of. If you ctrl-click on the `assertThrows`, where do you end up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be possible that you have a really old version of JUnit Jupiter in your classpath.

The milestone release 5.0.0-M3 (November 2016, [release notes](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.0/user-guide/#release-notes-5.0.0-m3)) added the return type to `assertThrows`. The version in your classpath seems to be older than that.

Make sure that you use a recent version of JUnit.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It turns out that I used old version of `JUNIT Jupiter`.

I had such dependencies in my `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.0-M2'
}
```

When I updated them to [the newest version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine/5.5.2):

```
dependencies {
     testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-engine', version: '5.5.2'
}
```

it worked as expected.